# How to read object properly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, javascript-objects

I am new to programming and recently began learning Javascript, I have a problem that appeared in few exercises that I made. I searched the site for more information but have not found a solution for my problem. I apologize in advance for my bad english and if this is not the right place or the right way to ask this question because this is my first post in Stackoverflow.

Currently practicing HTML templates. Assuming that the code is correct, I'm not sure where I'm wrong. Loading code into the browser and Handlebars gives me an error: "Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined". I tried to debug and saw that when I tried to take a value from `date` object it gives back undefined. In previous exercise had a similar problem in which I tried to read JSON object and did not manage to parse it and returned again undefined. Can you help me, I am stuck on this problem for some time.

```js
var data = {
  animals: [{
    name: 'Lion',
    url: 'https://susanmcmovies.files.wordpress.com/2014/12/the-lion-king-wallpaper-the-lion-king-2-simbas-pride-4685023-1024-768.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Turtle',
    url: 'http://www.enkivillage.com/s/upload/images/a231e4349b9e3f28c740d802d4565eaf.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Dog'
  }, {
    name: 'Cat',
    url: 'http://i.imgur.com/Ruuef.jpg'
  }, {
    name: 'Dog Again'
  }]
}

window.onload = function() {
  var htmlTemplate = document.getElementsByClassName('container-template').innerHTML;
  var template = Handlebars.compile(htmlTemplate);

  for (let x of data.animals) {
    if (x.hasOwnProperty('url')) { //x.url
      x.hasUrl = true;
    } else {
      x.hasUrl = false;
    }
  }

  document.getElementsByClassName('container').innerHTML = template(data);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Animals & Batman</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
  </div>

  <script class="container-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <h1>Animals</h1>
    {{#each animals}} 
      {{#if hasUrl}}
          <li>
              <a href="{{url}}">See a {{name}}</a>
          </li>
      {{else}}
          <li>
              <a href="http://cdn.playbuzz.com/cdn/3170bee8-985c-47bc-bbb5-2bcb41e85fe9/d8aa4750-deef-44ac-83a1-f2b5e6ee029a.jpg">No link for {{name}}, here is Batman!</a>
          </li>
      {{/if}} 
    {{/each}}
  </script>

  <script src="../handlebars-v4.0.5.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="../jquery-3.1.0.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="./main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with parsing JSON. Your `data` object doesn't need to be parsed because it is already a javascript object. I'm pretty sure the problem is because `document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array. Try `documents.getElementsByClassName("container-template")[0].innerhtml`

Comment: "You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means." [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, not a single one - since multiple elements on a page can have the same class.

What you probably want is to use the `id` instead of class:

```
<script id="container-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

var htmlTemplate = document.getElementById('container-template').innerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this helped me alot. With this problem I realized how much i don't know about DOM, arrays and objects.